# Missing type arguments for generic class Class<T> where T is a type-variable

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I use Oracle JDK 7 and when I build project I get that message:

```
missing type arguments for generic class Class<T> where T is a type-variable: 
T extends Object declared in class Class
```

Here is the class:

```
public class Among {
private static final Class<?>[] EMPTY_PARAMS = new Class[0]; //warning line
```

Any ideas how to solve it. It is used at many places and I have many warnings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
private static final Class<?>[] EMPTY_PARAMS = new Class<?>[0];
```

Note the `<?>` at the instantiation of the array.